# Scilab, draw a lot of dots

Tags: scilab

I have a matrix, where row is a single dot. First column - X, second - Y, last - Z. I doesn`t have any analitic function mapped X,Y->Z. And I want to display this dots in 3d graph for determining clusters, etc. How I can do it? I founded the function params3d which takes 3 vectors (x, y, z) and then displays this dots connected by polyline. How i can display only dots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn the lines off by adding the following lines after plotting your figure:

```
// Turn lines off so we just have points
e = gce();
e.line_mode="off";
e.mark_mode="on";
```

I got this from a question I answered about plotting with `params3d` a while ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211789/scilab-rgb-color-plot-trying-to-color-each-mark-with-its-respective-color/19316520#19316520).